# Декодирование GET параметров

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Возможно, банальный вопрос, тем не менее напишу здесь, потому что искал в сети решение, однако решения не подошли.

Формировал Get-параметры через JQuery, таким образом:

```
$url = 'https://site-name.ru/';           
if ($client_org !== '') $url+='?org='+ frmMain.sOrg.value;
console.log($url);
$(location).attr('href', $url);
```

Затем пытался декодировать в PHP:

```
if (!empty($_GET['org']))
{
     $Comp1 = $_GET['org'];
     if (!preg_match('//u', $Comp1)) {
     $Comp = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251", $_GET['org']);
}
```

Однако выдает все равно казяброкадабры. 
Варианты:

```
$Comp1 = urldecode($_GET['org']);
```

также не подошли. Есть что-нибудь такое, что может единообразно кодировать в Jquery и декодировать в PHP?

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в `$_GET['org']` приходит.

Comment: В GET['org'] 
 -
 %22%CA%EE%EC%EF%E0%ED%E8%FF%20%D5%EE%EB%E8%E4%E5%E9%20%CF%F0%EE%E8%E7%E2%EE%E4%F1%F2%E2%EE%22%20%CE%CE%CE%20-%D1%EE%EA%EE%EB%EE%E2%E0%20%DF.%20(5484). Тоесть русский текст, что закодирован был в скрипте JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Кодировку работы скриптов на сервере, базы данных и страниц сайта сделайте одинаковую - **UTF-8** (CP1251 для современных задач уже давно устарела).

> В GET['org'] - %22%CA%EE%EC%EF%E0%ED%E8%FF%20%D5%EE%EB%E8%E4%E5%E9%20%CF%F0‌​%EE%E8%E7%E2%EE%E4%F‌​1%F2%E2%EE%22%20%CE%‌​CE%CE%20-%D1%EE%EA%E‌​E%EB%EE%E2%E0%20%DF.‌​%20(5484). Тоесть русский текст, что закодирован был в скрипте JQuery

Это данные пришедшие от пользователя в кодировке CP1251. Вот перевод строки в читабельный UTF-8:

```
<?php
$str = urldecode('%22%CA%EE%EC%EF%E0%ED%E8%FF%20%D5%EE%EB%E8%E4%E5%E9%20%CF%F0%EE%E8%E7%E2%EE%E4%F1%F2%E2%EE%22%20%CE%CE%CE%20-%D1%EE%EA%EE%EB%EE%E2%E0%20%DF');
$str = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Результат

```
string(86) ""Компания Холидей Производство" ООО -Соколова Я"
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14635c9cd25fad9246a6d20f076e44cd1a8e4bac

Comment: К сожалению проект ветхий, там даже контент через блоки таблиц выполнены, хотя это прошлый век. По-хорошему, там все надо переписывать с нуля. Однако это не моя пока задача, потому и кодировки менять мне не позволено там, так что CP1251 поменять нельзя. За ответ спасибо.

Comment: Не работает ваш пример.

Comment: Если вы работаете в CP1251, то соответственно вам не надо переводить пришедшие данные в UTF-8 командой iconv(), а достаточно только использовать urldecode(). P.S. Мой пример работает для перевода пришедших данных в UTF-8. В этом вы можете убедиться перейдя по ссылке из ответа.

Answer (score 0):

encodeURIComponent(str); не подходит для ваших целей?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Ну и хотелось бы посмотреть на строку, которую вы пытаетесь закодировать и результат работы РНР скрипта

Comment: строка просто русский текст, например: ""Компания Холидей Производство" ООО -Соколова Я. (5484)", которую я get-параметром передаю в url

Comment: Ваш код пишет мне тогда такую талмуду: 2522%25CA%25EE%25EC%25EF%25E0%25ED%25E8%25FF%2520%25D5%25EE%25EB%25E8%25E4%25E5%25E9%2520%25CF%25F0%25EE%25E8%25E7%25E2%25EE%25E4%25F1%25F2%25E2%25EE%2522%2520%25CE%25CE%25CE%2520-%25D1%25EE%25EA%25EE%25EB%25EE%25E2%25E0%2520%25DF.%2520(5484)